# Login Validation Against Active Directory C# - Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to validate credentials in Active Directory for an MVC Web App (C#) I'm writing on Visual Studio for Mac. In searching for answers, I've noticed a lot of NotImplementedExceptions and other strange occurrences. 
Here is a (non-comprehensive) list of things I've tried and things that have failed.

First, this code:

```
 string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

 try
 {
     //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
     // This line throws a not implemented exception
     object obj = entry.NativeObject;

     DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
     {
          Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")"
     };
     search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

     Console.WriteLine(search.ToString());

     SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

     //Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());

     if (null == result)
     {
         return false;
     }

     //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
     _path = result.Path;
     _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
}
        return true;
```

The line `object obj = entry.NativeObject` throws a `NotImplementedException` I've tried commenting out the line (since `obj` is never used elsewhere) but to no avail. I have tried other variations of very similar code as well.

The other route I attempted was this code:

```
var creds = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var srvid = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(adPath);
// This line throws a NotImplementedException
var conn = new LdapConnection(srvid, creds);

try
{
    conn.Bind();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return false;
}

conn.Dispose();

return true;
```

And other variations of the same idea. The line `var conn = new LdapConnection(srvid, creds);` throws a `NotImplementedException`

Finally, I went a simpler route and used

```
Membership.ValidateUser(model.username, model.password)
```

Since this is a Web Api and I am using a controller. This requires some code in the Web.config [available here](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/). It, too, throws a `NotImplementedException`.

So do these three common methods all rely on the same underlying function that hasn't been implemented in VS for Mac yet? Or is there something I'm missing? Also if there is any workaround someone could offer, it would be very well appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only manually achieve that via Novell Ldap library at this stage. Microsoft is working on cross platform `System.DirectoryServices` for .NET Core, but whether that would extend its coverage to Mono is unknown.

Comment: This question/answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330705/working-with-directoryservices-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'm trying out Novell.Directory.Ldap right now. I'm getting `Invalid Credentials` errors, which I would consider a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to reference Microsoft.DirectoryServices.dll

[System.DirectoryServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Second, you need to run this queries with a domain account with grant access. Take care when you publish in server (iis) or other because the service run this code and it had to have permission on it.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957522/accessing-active-directory-from-asp-net-mvc-using-c-sharp)

Sorry for my English :D

Comment: It is included, otherwise the error would be something along the lines of an undefined class: judging by the Exception, the class is defined but not implemented. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement doesn't exist as a library for Visual Studio for Mac ([referencing Mono's codebase](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class)), so PrincipalContext is undefined (I had tried that as well, sorry I forgot to mention it in the question).

Comment: ok, then you must to use this class https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Directory.LDAP/Mono.Directory.LDAP/LDAP.cs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the kind efforts of [Javier Jimenez Matilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377199/javier-jimenez-matilla), [bnem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795673/bnem), and [Lexi Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li), I got it to work. Part of the issue was a configuration problem that I unfortunately can't disclose (confidentiality and whatnot), but here's the final code:

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
try
{
    var conn = new LdapConnection();
    conn.Connect(domain, 389);
    conn.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, $"{subDomain}\\{username}", password);
    return true;
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

A few things to note. First, that `LdapConnection` is actually `Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection`. Secondly, the hard-coded `389` is the port which [LDAP likes to communicate over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#Protocol_overview). Thirdly, the parameter `$"{subDomain}\\{username}"` is the way the username appears to AD. For my particular case, the domain is of the form "corporation.mycompany.com", and in AD the username appears `corporation\username`. So in this example, `string subDomain = "corporation"`